# How can I hide the right arrow on a list view?

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey

I'm using Delphi XE8 and I want to remove/hide that little right arrow in my list views, how can I do this?

In this image you can see the arrow that I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: Have you read about [`ItemAppearance`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListView.Appearances.TPublishedAppearance.ItemAppearance) property?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
MyListView.ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Accessory.Visible := False;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!